# An error occurred during the process of creating Nuxt as '[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event'

Tags: nuxtjs3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ynKk.png)
This is a newly created nuxt demo, and I didn't do anything, but this bug appeared
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cqZq.png)

I searched for error prompts, but there is no solution. It is related to Nuxt...